# Authenticating twitter account in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, twitter

I have an interface which is for authenticating twitter account. If I input the credentials and submit, I need to know, whether the account is valid or not.

Preferably, I would like to get this implemented this with AccountManager.

Is this possible?

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Best Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example of logging in on twitter with oauth.  If you want to actually get the username/password from the user you need to apply for xauth permission from twitter explaining why you think you need to do that. Sorry this example does not use AccountManager but it does work well. http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/